# Music playback software similar to iTunes with FLAC support

Tags: windows, music

I'm searching for a software which I can use to view and playback my music collection. It should be able to only show music from specific albums, artists or folders on my computer, sort my music by those parameters and offer standard playback functionality such as random, repeat all, repeat one and so on. Also I want to be able to create playlists. I'm currently using VLC media player, but that is not really convenient as I have to manually navigate to the folder I want to open, or create playlists for every one of them.
So basically what I want is iTunes with support for not only MP3 and M4A audio, but also FLAC (very important) and WMA (not so important) files. I'm using Windows (7 & 8.1 at the moment, soon only Windows 10). Preferably free software, but I would be ok throwing a couple of bucks at some program that caters to those requirements.
And **no**, I'm **not** searching for software with which I can convert my FLAC files to another format that iTunes understands. Thanks!

Comment: foobar2000. Still the best music player for windows. Does have everything what you are looking for

Comment: I've gone with MediaMonkey for now - but that looks interesting as well, I might check it out some time. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com)

I add the same problem. MediaMonkey answers all your needs.

#### Your needs

- Read FLAC (and rip to FLAC too): definitely.
- Read WMA: I think so (not sure I have that many).
- Windows 7: definitely; didn't make the jump yet, but the Windows 10 upgrade did not mark it as incompatible software.
- Free: a free version exists. I think I paid $35 to get a lifetime gold license (I needed some of the additional features, such as autosync format conversion).

#### Bonus needs

Not an exhaustive list, but some I found great:

- Intelligent playlists: instead of specifying your tracks one by one, generate playlists by telling the software to add all tracks from that artist, in the order of release date, disc number, track number (not one of the three, the three in that order)
- Autosync format conversion (gold feature, I think): I listen to my music on an iPod, which does not understand FLAC. But you can configure MediaMonkey to convert all your files when syncing with a specific device (when syncing with the iPod, convert all FLAC files to ALAC or MP3 392 kbps VBR, …).

---

<sub>This answer does not yet match my quality standard. I lack the time right now but I wanted to provide a solution quickly. I'll be back. Comment to ping me if this goes stale, as I am quite busy at this time and might forget.</sub>

Comment: Looks good, I'll check it out later, thanks!